# Python select value on same level in json if matches

Tags: python, json, list

I have an api call from my python file that returns me some data in json. I want to create a list in python with all the different item ids with matching description. I made a simplified version of it below which basically shows where I am stuck currently. Also I am not sure how to ask this question so if someone has a better title please edit it.

Right now what I have thought of is saving the size of items array and loop through that but I can't figure out how to select name value from the same level if desc_id is matching. I'm not even sure if this is the right way to do that.

```
json
{
  'items':[
    {
      'id': 111,
      'desc_id': 1,
    },
    {
      'id': 222,
      'desc_id': 2
    },
    {
      'id': 333,
      'desc_id': 2
    }
  ],
  'desc': [
    {
      'desc_id': 1,
      'name': 'test',
      ...
    },
    {
      'desc_id': 2,
      'name': 'something else',
      ...
    },
  ]

}
```

Desired output in python:

```
[['111', 'test', ...]['222', 'something else', ...]['333', 'something else', ...]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create `desc` as a dictionary of id: name pairs. Then when you iterate through `items` it's a nested lookup of the `item['desc_id']`

```py
desc = {item['desc_id']: item['name'] for item in data['desc']}

items = [[item['id'], desc[item['desc_id']]] for item in data['items']]

items
[[111, 'test'], [222, 'something else'], [333, 'something else']]
```

Comment: What if the desc json part has more names in it? I created this just a simplified test case but in my real api call there are multiple different names in desc
@C.Nivs

Comment: I've also edited the question code to make it more understandable I think.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I figured out how to use it with multiple names.

`desc = {item['desc_id']: [item['name'], item['name2']] for item in data['desc']}`